# Can't make my Listview appear

Tags: android

I'm working on an android application and cannot seem to make my listView appear when the app is run. I've been toggling with some of the xml but I'm still rather new and android updates quite often so tutorials are constantly becoming outdated.The actual java code seems fine to me I can't see much difference there. I could really use an extra pair of eyes on this , maybe there is something I'm missing.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }

    @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
        }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }



import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;




/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today, colder than bumblefuck",
                "Friday, condsider moving",
                "Saturday, not even gonna bother",
                "Sunday, Partly Cloudy",
                "Monday, Hell Froze over",
                "Tuesday, Cloudy with a chance of meatballs",
                "Wednesday,Light Showers"
        };
        List<String> weekForeCast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        ArrayAdapter<String> bindIt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForeCast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false).findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(bindIt);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id ="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:enabled="false">

</TextView>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.alesterlewis.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alesterlewis.sunshine.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post code snippets

Comment: Hey please post the main activity xml, fragment xml, mainactivity.java and mainfragment.java code seperately to make sense out of it;-0

Comment: The cause for your bug is just a new view inflating and getting returned as the view of the fragment. Check the explanation in the answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you set an adapter for your list? Maybe your adapter list is empty for some reason.

**UPDATE**

Try to anticipate the view creation:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today, colder than bumblefuck",
                "Friday, condsider moving",
                "Saturday, not even gonna bother",
                "Sunday, Partly Cloudy",
                "Monday, Hell Froze over",
                "Tuesday, Cloudy with a chance of meatballs",
                "Wednesday,Light Showers"
        };
        List<String> weekForeCast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        ArrayAdapter<String> bindIt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForeCast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(bindIt);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I did I updated it with some code if you would like to take a look.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try that way!

Comment: It worked thank you so much , it was such a rookie mistake . I'll make less of those . Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inflating a new view while returning from the onCreateView. Thus, the one in which you had set the adapter and for the listview is lost. This is the bug.

First inflate the layout for the fragment in the view

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Then initialise its components, here you can set the list view adapter, etc and if you would have had more view, initialised the same.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> bindIt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,weekForeCast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(bindIt);
```

and in the end return the same view that was initially infalated and worked upon!